# Why following php regexp is not accepting ' and &?

Tags: php, regex

Why following regular expression is not accepting `'` and `&`?

I want to accept only `'` and `@` and `&` and `.` Currently, it's only accepting `@` and `.`.

```
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9.'@& ]+$/", $source) == 1)
    $err[] = "Wrong value for source field";
```

Is it correct regular expression to accepting my specified characters?

**Update :**

```
$source =  $_POST['source'];

if(!empty($source)){

    if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9.'@& ]+$/", $source) !== 1)
      $err[] = "Wrong value for source field";  

    elseif(strlen($source) > 50)
        $err[] =  "Max length exceed for source field";
}
```

Comment: It should accept all those 4 characters. Check your $source and please include a failing test case.

Comment: @Chris: Not necessary.

Comment: It's good regex. http://regexr.com/39qg8

Comment: @nhahtdh $source value is = `I'm a developer & @ .`

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9.'@& ]+$` matches `I'm a developer & @`

Comment: btw you don't need `==1` just use: `if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9.'@& ]+$/", $source))`

Comment: @anubhava I updated my question. Please check it. I'm using this..

Comment: STRANGE! USING THIS `!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9.@'& ]+$/", $source)` ti's accepting `&` not `'`

Comment: Coding style. And magic_quotes.

Comment: Try using `'/^[a-zA-Z0-9.@\'& ]+$/'` (singly quoted string) instead.